# Why are not working my roles in my MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, roles, privileges

I am currently learning about user privileges and roles in MySQL. At this time I am learning how to create custom roles, grant privileges to them and finally create some users just for testing this new roles. The thing is that, I don't know why but, even though the roles are correctly assigned to the users, when I login using them I cannot see any schema just like if I didn't have any privilege. The script that I am using is the next one:

For creating a new role:

```
CREATE ROLE 'read_db';
```

For setting privileges in the "bdatosventas" database:

```
GRANT SELECT ON bdatosventas.* TO 'read_db';
```

Creating a new user:

```
CREATE USER 'test_read_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
```

Setting the role for this new user:

```
GRANT 'read_db' TO 'test_read_user'@'localhost';
```

Verifying the privileges with:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'test_read_user'@'localhost';
```

And as output I get:

```
GRANT `read_db` TO `test_read_user`@`localhost`
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `test_read_user`@`localhost`...
```

Finally a good:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

So I guess the role is correctly assigned and should be working.
But when I get into phpMyAdmin using that new user, it doesn't show me any schema, cannot see my database "bdatosventas", just one called 'information_schema'. What is the problem?, thank you.

Comment: Do you also have a user `test_reader_user@%`? The user from localhost and the user from any IP address are different users, and may have different privileges. Try `SELECT USER();` when you are logged in as the test user.

Comment: The query says "test_read_user@localhost", I have not created any other user using a name alike. Is there any way to see the actual privileges instead of just retrieve the role name?

Comment: I have the same problem. for some reason the privileges are not propagated from the role to the user. Hence, I am also unable to login with the user. If I use the Workbench to create the Users, then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I found this problem too. I fixed it by running sql `set default role <role_name> to <user>` following these documents:

- [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html#:~:text=SHOW%20GRANTS%20Statement%E2%80%9D.-,Activating,-Roles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html#:%7E:text=SHOW%20GRANTS%20Statement%E2%80%9D.-,Activating,-Roles).
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-default-role/

Answer (score 1):

ok, this is what solved it for me.

After creating the Roles, Granting privileges to the roles, creating users and then assigning User Membership to the roles, one important step is to ACTIVATE the roles:

`SET ROLE ALL;`